# "Big Pig" dice game code goes in infinite loop :C

Tags: c, random, dice

Hello I'm new to c and i'm currently learning with my university curriculum so i need to abide by these rules: We can't use arrays or global variables.

So i've been trying to make a dice game named "big pig". I'm right now creating the function the computer is going to use to play the game called "play_computer()". There is also a function called "computer_strategy_decider()".Computer_strategy_decider() is supposed to pick from yes or no. I just made a rand function that calls either 1 or 2 to make that work. Play_computer() let's you pick two dices and from there it needs to calculate the score. If you pick only one one, then your score doesn't increase and your game is terminated. If you et two ones you get 25 added. If you get any other double value for example a , is added such as (a+a)*2 or 4*a. And lastly if you get two random numbers the computer gets to decide if it wants to continue. That's where the computer_strategy_decider() comes in..

The problem comes with the play_computer() function. Everything seems to be working well when the computer rolls two different values and doesn't continue. It terminates ok. But if it wants to continue it goes in an infinite loop. The infinite loop also has the same dice values.
The same loop happens when doubles are rolled. Something in my code doesn't loop properly. I don't know whether it is something to do with rand() or not. I don't think it's rand() since i use rand() on computer_strategy_decider(). My theory is it's hopefully something small i have missed.

My code was working an hour ago before i added some changes so that's why im frustrated haha.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int computer_strategy_decider(){

int deci;
srand(time(NULL));
deci=1+ (int) rand() % 2;
    return deci;}






int play_computer(round_number,strategy){

  int roll_1,roll_2,cntrl_var=0,score_comp=0;
  char answ;

  printf("\nRound %d-- My Turn:",round_number);printf("\n---------------------------------");

  while(cntrl_var==0){
   srand(time(NULL));
   roll_1 = 1 + (int) rand() % 6;
   roll_2 = 1 + (int) rand() % 6;

  printf("\nI got --> [Dice 1]: %d [Dice 2]: %d",roll_1,roll_2);
  if(roll_1==roll_2 && roll_1!=1){
    score_comp=score_comp+roll_1*4;
    printf("\nScore: %d",score_comp);printf("\nDoubles! Roll again!");}
  else if(roll_1==1 && roll_2==1){
    score_comp=score_comp+25;
    printf("\nScore: %d",score_comp);printf("\nDoubles! Roll again!");}
  else if(roll_1==1 || roll_2==1){
    cntrl_var=1;
    printf("\nYou got a single one! End of your turn!");}
  else{
    score_comp=score_comp+roll_1+roll_2;
    printf("\nScore: %d",score_comp);
    while(cntrl_var==0){
      printf("\nDo you want to continue (Y/N)?");
      if (strategy==1){
        printf("Y");
        break;}
      else if (strategy==2){
        printf("N");
        break;}}
    if (strategy==1)
        cntrl_var=0;
    else if (strategy==2)
        cntrl_var=1;
    else
        cntrl_var=0;}}

  printf("\nMy Score: %d",score_comp);

  return score_comp;}

int main(){

int round_no=1,deci;
deci=computer_strategy_decider();
play_computer(round_no,deci);
}
```

Comment: have you stepped through the code in a debugger, or at least, put printf statements in the code to see where it is going and the variable values.  Learning how to debug is a critical skill.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once

Comment: Thank you! I guess when i put the srand in the while loop it was "executed more than once" per say and that caused the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I put the srand in the while loop and that caused the srand to be called multiple times. So i put the srand above the loop. That fixed it!